# Stopping a service / blocking a port on a stopped ESXI5 - Where are the conf files?

Tags: firewall, vmware-esxi, service, ntp

We've been victim of an ntp-amplification attack, hence, the need to disable the service. and/or block some ports

I'm connecting with some rescue mode on my ESXI *(5.0 update 1)*

I had to mount my drives manually so that I can access my data.

I extracted `state.gz`&`local.gz`, but the content of /etc/ is quite     disconcerting :

no `/etc/ntp.conf`, nor `/etc/init.d`
I also looked for an hypothetic `etc/vmware/firewall`, but it doesn't exist either.

Anyway : my conclusion is that I have to block at least outgoing port 123 (ntp), *and maybe also restrict UDP to some IPs*, but I just don't understand why no conf file seem to exist (the /etc contains shadow, hosts & a few other things... but no init.d or firewal looks weird to me)

In case it can help, here's one of the lines of said attack, I just removed the IP

`dateTime - srcIp:srcPort - dstIp:dstPort - protocol - flags - bytes - reason`

`2016.09.03 13:36:46 CEST   *MY-IP*:123         *VICTIM-IP*:56173    UDP      ---           468 ATTACK:NTP`

Here are some of the (numerous) documentation I browsed, but with not any of referred files existing in what I extracted, I'm a bit confused.

[VMWare article explaining how to set firewall rules](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2008226)

[Article explaining how to access & modify esxi config files on a non-running ESXI](http://www.itechlounge.net/2013/05/vmware-how-to-reset-esxi-root-password/)

Comment: Do you not have another firewall in front of your ESXi host/s management ports? If not that's far from best-practice.

Comment: @Chopper3 I'm not sure to understand what kind of firewall you're speaking about.  For other machines, we use AWS a lot and always have restricting security groups, but in that case, the ESXI host is a physical machine, and no higher layer is available.
_Our provider offers an option to put a material firewall called "ASA", all I know is it's physical, using a reliable Cisco stuff_

Our main problem is that since the ESXI is not running, we only have access to the raw HDD data.  Those missing config files are quite puzzling.

Comment: The only "solution" we found was to restart the ESXI _without_ any config change.
The files I was looking for were all here that time, and I was able to disable my NTP service quickly, before getting blocked again by my provider.

The thing is : **We still don't understand why no one of those config files was in the extracted zips**

We shouldn't need this for this server, but anyway, any insights would be appreciated.